# Set a specific date to a datetimepicker in c#

Tags: c#, string-to-datetime

I have a date coming from a database as a string. I want to set it to a datetimepicker.

The problem is, it can be in many formats, such as:

> d/m/yyyy
>   d/mm/yyyy
>   dd/m/yyyy
>   dd/mm/yyyy

I don't know how to do it.

If I can convert this to something like `dd/mm/yyyy` I can show it in datetime picker.

How can I do this programmatically ?

Comment: I think that these post will give you the answer you need:

[Get Date Fomat From String][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513944/find-out-the-date-time-format-of-string-date-in-c-sharp

Comment: People, if you're going to downvote a question, please at least leave a comment.  Simply, downvoting someone is a pretty useless gesture.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it like that:

```
    string inputStringDate = "01/01/2001";
    DateTime outputDateTime;
    string[] formats = { "d/M/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy", "dd/m/yyyy", "dd/mm/yyyy" };
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputStringDate, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outputDateTime))
    {
        //There you have your DateTime in outputDateTime var
    }
```