# Detecting the date format from a date string

Tags: c#, datetime

In my application I am having the possibility of getting date in two formats "dd/MM/yyyy" and "MM/dd/yyyy", and I want to have both date formats in "dd/MM/yyyy" format, I tried using `DateTime.TryParseExact`

```
string date = "12/21/2017";
DateTime dt;
if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
}
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
```

My problem is that, my code works fine and if I have the date input like this 12/21/2017 (MM/dd/yyyy) and converts the date to 21/12/2017 (dd/MM/yyyy) but does not works if the date is like this 11/10/2017 which may be (MM/dd/yyyy) or (dd/MM/yyyy) it gives 10/11/2017 by considering the date format as (MM/dd/yyyy).

Is there any way to get the date format from the date so that I can use ParseExact to parse the date to (dd/MM/yyyy) format, or is there any way to convert the date formats which may be (MM/dd/yyyy) or (dd/MM/yyyy) to (dd/MM/yyyy).

**Edit**
Based on the conversation with you, I got that it is ambiguous in certain dates, I am going to ask the Front End team to give DateTime object rather than a date string. Thank you so much.

Comment: Very closer to this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513944/find-out-the-date-time-format-of-string-date-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If you get the data as a `string` without any other information you won't be able to say if 01/02/2017 is the first of february or the second of january. How could you?

Comment: @RikudouSennin Do you have a `DateTime` instance? Thought you just have a `string`.

Comment: It's unclear what you expect to be possible here. You have a string that's ambiguous. It's not like strings have extra information embedded within them to tell you how they were created. I would strongly suggest working your way back up the data chain to try to remove the ambiguity. By the time you've *got* a string like "01/02/2017" that could mean February 1st or January 2nd, you're basically out of luck.

Comment: You have to be certain of the format or else this question is quite useless, if format can differ on each input they (user?) will have to provide the format

Comment: DateTime **HAS NO FORMAT**. It's a binary value, just like integers and decimals. How it appears *when formatted into a string* depends on the culture specified in `ToString()` or `String.Format()`. If the culture isn't specified, the current application's (actually thread's) culture is used

Comment: Is it a person who gives the date or are you scraping data or something else. If its a user you could add a format field

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I am going to ask the front end team to provide DateTime rather than a plain date string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You do not seem to understand. A **DATE** (string) has a format (eg. dd/MM/YY) that's what were talking about. Not a datetime object

Comment: @EpicKip no, that's a *string* that contains a date representation. The resulting DateTime has no format. You can't know what the string's format is just by inspecting the string. What does 03/04 stand for?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OMFG i just said we're not talking about the datetime yet. To get a datetime from a string you need to know the format.... And no shit you can't get it from inspecting the string that's what we're talking about here read

Comment: @EpicKip yes, I know. I answer at least 3 *identical* questions every day. It's hard to find which one to pick as a duplicate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good for you, don't forget to read even if you answer a lot of the same questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the Date time format of string date in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513944/find-out-the-date-time-format-of-string-date-in-c-sharp)